# Flutter : isolate the right hand of Future<Either>

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, dartz

iam using riverpod with dartz , nad iam facing a problem that when using a future provider with my function i can't get my hand on the either as well , how can i isolate what i want to retrieve from the function with error handling  !

my provider code :

```
final activeCourseProvider =
    FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<List<CourseModel>, int>((ref, yearId) {
  final _courseRepository = ref.watch(coursesRepositoryProvider);
  return _courseRepository.activeCourses(yearId);
});
```

my function code :

```
Future<Either<ApiFailures, List<CourseModel>>> activeCourses(int yearId) async {
   try{ final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse("http://msc-mu.com/api_verfication.php"),
        body: {"flag": "selectcourses", "year": "$yearId"});
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var l = json.decode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
        var courses = l.map((e) => CourseModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
        return right(courses);
      } else {
        return left(ApiFailures.notFound());
      }
    } on SocketException {
      return left(ApiFailures.noConnection());
    } on HttpException {
      return left(ApiFailures.notFound());
    }
  }
```

the error that pops up is : `The return type 'Future<Either<ApiFailures, List<CourseModel>>>' isn't a 'Future<List<CourseModel>>', as required by the closure's context.`

Comment: final activeCourseProvider =
 FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<Either<ApiFailures, List<CourseModel>, int>

Comment: @croxx5f that won't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your Provider `activeCourseProvider` is supposed to return a `List<CourseModel>`, not an `Either<ApiFailures, List<CourseModel>>`.

You could use `fold` the `Either` value as follows:

```
final activeCourseProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<List<CourseModel>, int>((ref, yearId) {
  final _courseRepository = ref.watch(coursesRepositoryProvider);
  return _courseRepository.fold<List<CourseModel>>(
    (ApiFailures failure) => {
      // Handle failure
      return [];
    },
    (List<CourseModel> r) => r
  );
});
```

However, you might also want to have your Provider returning an `Either<ApiFailures, List<CourseModel>>` value instead of a `List<CourseModel>`. That could be useful if you want to handle the `ApiFailures` further down in your presentation layer. This depends on your architecture.

Comment: I have handled the failures in my presentation layer , thanks alot thierry

Answer (score 0):

This is because you declare the function will return a Either result:

```
Future<Either<ApiFailures, List<CourseModel>>>
```

but when you pass the Type:

```
FutureProvider.autoDispose.family<List<CourseModel>
```

the either is not handled, change this:

```
return _courseRepository.activeCourses(yearId);
```

to

```
final result= _courseRepository.activeCourses(yearId);
if(result.isRight()){
return result.gerOrElse(()=>null);
}else{
///handle left result
}
```